# Reduce max memory requriement for Kuramoto model code

Tags: performance-tuning, graphs-and-networks

I have some code for running the Kuramoto model on a random graph. Even with 128GB of virtual memory assigned, the routine sometimes exceeds its maximum allowance and is killed (I am running this on a research cluster).

What I don't really understand is why the script (which solves a large system of differential equations and averages its asymptotic behavior over a large number samples) is using so much memory. What does it all go on? The graph isn't huge so its not that.

Perhaps there is a way to reduce the maximum memory requirement?

```
SeedRandom[];
import = 0;
evaltime = 10000;
preludetime = 5000;
nsamples = 10000;
numpoints = 20;
min = 1;
max = 5;
numiterations = 2;
\[Rho] = 5000;
\[Zeta] = 1;
deg = 20;
nfreq = 0;
\[Theta]start = 0;
tmax = evaltime;
folder = "foldtest1000/";
hypdistance[x_, y_, \[Zeta]_] := 
  Module[{x1, y1, x2, y2, r1, \[Theta]1, r2, \[Theta]2, c}, 
   x1 = x[[1]];
   y1 = x[[2]];
   x2 = y[[1]];
   y2 = y[[2]];
   polar1 = ToPolarCoordinates[{x1, y1}];
   polar2 = ToPolarCoordinates[{x2, y2}];
   r1 = polar1[[1]];
   r2 = polar2[[1]];
   \[Theta]1 = polar1[[2]];
   \[Theta]2 = polar2[[2]];
   \[Delta] = Pi - Abs[Pi - Abs[\[Theta]1 - \[Theta]2]];
   \[Gamma] = 
    Cosh[\[Zeta] r1] Cosh[\[Zeta] r2] - 
     Sinh[\[Zeta] r1] Sinh[\[Zeta] r2] Cos[\[Delta]];
   1/\[Zeta] ArcCosh[\[Gamma]]];
edges[v1_, R_, \[Zeta]_] := 
  Module[{}, Select[v1, hypdistance[#[[1]], #[[2]], \[Zeta]] < R &]];

gr6[vert_, R_, \[Zeta]_] := 
  Graph[vert, 
   UndirectedEdge @@@ edges[Subsets[vert, {2}], R, \[Zeta]], 
   VertexCoordinates -> vert];
d[R_, \[Alpha]_] := 
    ProbabilityDistribution[\[Alpha] Sinh[\[Alpha] r]/(
    Cosh[\[Alpha] R] - 1), {r, 0, R}];
hrgg[\[Rho]_, \[Zeta]_, deg_] := 
  Module[{R, \[Alpha]}, 
   R = 2/\[Zeta] Log[(8 \[Rho])/(Pi deg)]; \[Alpha] = \[Zeta]; 
   polarpts = 
    Transpose[{RandomVariate[d[R, \[Alpha]], \[Rho]], 
      RandomReal[{-Pi, Pi}, \[Rho]]}];
   pts = FromPolarCoordinates[polarpts];
   v = pts;
   graph6 = gr6[v, R, \[Zeta]];
   gr1 = graph6; gr1];
plot[\[Rho]_, \[Zeta]_, deg_] := Module[{},
   SeedRandom[];
   name = 
    StringJoin[
     RandomChoice[{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", 
       "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", 
       "w", "x", "y", "z"}], ToString[RandomInteger[{0, 9}]], 
     RandomChoice[{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", 
       "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", 
       "w", "x", "y", "z"}], 
     RandomChoice[{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", 
       "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", 
       "w", "x", "y", "z"}]];
   \[Theta]start = 0;
   SeedRandom[];
   rg1 = hrgg[\[Rho], \[Zeta], deg];
   rg2 = Subgraph[rg1, ConnectedComponents[rg1][[1]], 
     GraphLayout -> "BalloonEmbedding"];
   Print[rg2];
   rg2 = AdjacencyGraph[AdjacencyMatrix[rg2]];
   Nosc = Length@VertexList[rg2];
   gammadisp = 0.05;
   If[\[Theta]start == 0, 
    SeedRandom[]; \[Theta]start = RandomReal[{0, 2*Pi}, Nosc];];
   omegadata = VertexDegree[rg2];
   A = AdjacencyMatrix[rg2];
   B = N[IncidenceMatrix[
      Graph[UpperTriangularize[A]["NonzeroPositions"], 
       DirectedEdges -> True]]];
   X[\[Theta]_?VectorQ, \[Lambda]_] := 
    N[omegadata] - \[Lambda] B . Sin[\[Theta] . B];
   tnonconvex2 = ConstantArray[0, {numpoints, 2}];
   Clear[t1, t2, t3];
   For[i = 1, i <= numpoints, i++,
    a = ParametricNDSolveValue[{\[Theta]'[t] == 
        X[\[Theta][t], \[Lambda]], \[Theta][
         0] == \[Theta]start}, \[Theta], {t, 0, 
       evaltime}, {\[Lambda]}, AccuracyGoal -> 10, 
      PrecisionGoal -> 10, Method -> "StiffnessSwitching", 
      MaxSteps -> 1000000];
    solution = a[((max - min) (i - 1))/numpoints + min];
    Print["done ", i];
    g = rg1;
    samplepoints = 
     Sort@RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{preludetime, evaltime}], 
       nsamples];
    data = 
     Abs[1/Nosc Total[Exp[-I Mean[{solution[#]}]]]] & /@ 
      samplepoints;
    tnonconvex2[[i, 1]] = ((max - min) (i - 1))/numpoints + min;
    tnonconvex2[[i, 2]] = Mean[data];
    \[Theta]start = solution[evaltime];
    Print["Hello this is ", name];
    Print["I found that ", tnonconvex2[[i, 1 ;; 2]]];
    Export[StringJoin[folder, name, ".txt"], tnonconvex2];
    Print[
     ListPlot[Transpose[{samplepoints, data}], 
      PlotRange -> {{preludetime, evaltime}, {0, 1}}, Joined -> True]];
    ];
   ];
s = Table[0, {i, 1, numiterations}];
For[ct = 1, ct <= numiterations, ct++, plot[\[Rho], \[Zeta], deg];
 s[[ct]] = out; Print["----------"]; Print["Done iteration ", ct];
 Print["----------"];]
finaldata = Mean[s];
Print["Done"]
```

Comment: The problem is in `Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"` which calls an implicit method. These methods are very memory costly.

Comment: Which is the lowest memory method?

Comment: The default one, just remove the `Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"` option.